# Intel RealSense 3D camera cannot be initialized

Tags: windows, driver, intel, device-driver, realsense

I wonder why every once in a while, Intel RealSense 3D camera fails to start? I have re-installed the drivers and SDK as well as the DCM but still it is whacky and very unpredictable. Any idea what the source of the problem could be? It should be able to run the examples in the SDK in a normal working situation.

[image]

Well, previously that it couldn't init problem was that only two of the its drivers could be recognized (not the virtual driver) like the following but now all of its driver are recognized and still it can't init.
[image]

[image]

so I am receiving an init failed message when running the SDK examples.
Any pointer for fixing is really appreciated.

Comment: try disabling the regular webcam and rebooting.

Comment: it worked for me. It would be great if you can write this as an answer

Comment: This issue is also discussed at https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1830237, according to a now-deleted link-only answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are also showing an integrated webcam (other than the 3 RealSense listings), try disabling that so the RS camera can be seen as the primary.

Comment: Hi, can you please look at my question here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/562030 the camera doesn't initialize even though I first disabled and then even uninstalled the integrated laptop camera. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Looks more like a workaround than a solution but should do the trick as well

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can select the device you want to run the sample on in the menu "Device". If you installed the RealSense correctly and if the latest DCM is running (the current version is 1.4 if I remember), you should be able to select the RealSense device there and then run the sample.
Sometimes the DCM Service fails to start (e.g. if you force-restarted your machine recently). Then you just need to make the service restart and it should work.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I’m also facing the same problem (on windows 10), and found a way that solved it for me: search “Scanners and Cameras” in Control Panel, choose “Add Device”, under “Manufacturer” choose “Intel” and under “Model” choose “Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Virtual Driver” or the version you use, and continue to install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the right drivers? There are two versions of the real sense cameras. The Windows 10 works with Intel Real Sense R3 which has completely different architecture than its predecessor.